# Compile another source code in c source code during runtime

Tags: c

This is an extremely weird question, but I am still curious. I have a source code `a.c`, in it, I have some magic code that compiles a different code `b.c` in the same directory. Hence, during runtime, `b.c` is compiled and perhaps ran.

I apologize for this question to be vague, but is this something that's been done before? If not, is there any way to do so?

Comment: Why downvote this question? Am I the only one curious how this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**a.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    puts("a: compiling b.c");
    system("gcc -o b b.c");
    puts("a: executing b");
    system("./b");
    puts("a: done");
    return 0;
}
```

**b.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    puts("b: hello world");
    return 0;
}
```

**output**:

```
a: compiling b.c
a: executing b
b: hello world
a: done
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can `fork` and `exec` to run the compiler, and then `fork` and `exec` again to run the compiled code. The other option is to use the `system` function to run the compiler, and then call `system` again to run the compiled code.